# VBA excel error "This action wont work on multiple selection"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data to multiple sheets from one sheet, but I'm getting an error:

> This action won't work on multiple selection.

This is the code I'm using:

```
.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets(cell.Value).Range("A12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Adding to the above error: Im using table format to the destination since it is requirement. is this causing problem?

Comment: The error is  not connected with copying to multiple sheets. Excel does not allow copying of multiple not contiguous ranges. If you manually will try to select A1 and C1 and then you type `Ctrl + C` followed by `Ctrl + V` after one cell selection, both values will be pasted in adiacent columns. If you try (pressing Ctrl) selecting of  A1, C1 and B3 and type `Ctrl + C`, you will receive the error you mentioned...

Comment: You can copy the selected range using a trick: Inputting each selected cell in an bidimensional array (cell address plus cell value) and use the array to populate the  other sheet with the array values...

Comment: Would you need such a solution to copy your discontinuous range on the other sheets? Your question looks to refer only to the error definition/explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Thnaks

I was able to find answer.... destination were I paste is in table format so error accrued. Multiple selection copy is allowed, but pasting it in a pre defined table format is not allowed.

Solution: sort and copy required rows and paste

Thanks all.